# Get RuntimeMethodInfo from generic overloaded methods in non-generic static class

Tags: c#, system.reflection, methodinfo

I try to get runtime method infoes in static class. I have four static method inside the class and each name is equal, also parameter name is equal. The only difference is their types. One of four method has string parameter so it is easy to get method info. However the others don't working. I find several advice but that are not working.

All test code is here.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //ok
        var stringMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(string) });
        //not working
        var dictMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(Dictionary<,>) });
        //not working
        var genericMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(object) });
        //not working
        var listMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(List<>) });


        //not working
        var res = typeof(TestClass)
        .GetRuntimeMethods()
        .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("TestMethod"))
        .Select(m => new { Method = m, Parameters = m.GetParameters() })
        .FirstOrDefault(p =>
            p.Parameters.Length == 1
        && p.Parameters[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType
        && p.Parameters[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
        );

    }
}


public static class TestClass {
    public static bool TestMethod(string item) {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool TestMethod<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> item) {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool TestMethod<T>(T item) {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool TestMethod<T>(List<T> item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "don't working" means what exactly?

Comment: Returns null. They are working when only one generic with same name or different count of parameter etc. In my scenario, I get always null. In code, res line is an example from stackoverflow. Also it is return null

Comment: Sorry what do you expect it to return? It will return  the first `TestMethod` for which there is exactly on generic param which has a generic definition of `ICollection<>`. You have no such method.

Comment: Ok. What is Dictionary<,>? How I get each one method info? Obviously, I cannot get method info except with string parameter. So I try to understand why? And what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .net core 2.1 or greater, you can use `Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter` to let you refer to a generic parameter of a method. You can use that to create a generic type argument that will work with `GetMethod` (not available for `GetRuntimeMethod`).

```
var stringMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(string) });
Type[] dictionaryTypeParameters = { typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(1)) };
MethodInfo dictMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("TestMethod", 2, dictionaryTypeParameters);
MethodInfo listMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("TestMethod", 1, new[] { typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)) });
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("TestMethod", 1, new[] { Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0) });
```

Some interesting reading on the topic [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20377).

Comment: Note: I use .NET 5 and GetRuntimeMethod is worked and find the expected methods.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we would like to use this method to get any `MethodInfo` for the various `TestMethod`. Note that they all have exactly one parameter, so `p.Parameters.Length == 1` is useless:

1. Defined as `bool TestMethod(string item)`. We can use

```
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Method.IsGenericMethod)
```

2. Defined as `bool TestMethod<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> item)`

```
    .FirstOrDefault(p =>
        p.Method.IsGenericMethod &&
        p.Method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2)
```

3. Defined as `bool TestMethod<T>(T item)`

```
    .FirstOrDefault(p =>
        p.Method.IsGenericMethod &&
        p.Parameters[0].ParameterType == m.Method.GetGenericArguments()[0]
        )
```

4. Defined as `TestMethod<T>(List<T> item)`

```
    .FirstOrDefault(p =>
        p.Method.IsGenericMethod &&
        p.Parameters[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `generic` methods you have to query the `MethodInfo` object to get the appropriate method.

You can do it as below -

```
var dictMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod" && m.IsGenericMethod &&
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType && 
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>));
```

In your case, getting the `MethodInfo` for `TestMethod<T>` is bit tricky, but below should work -

```
var genericMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod" && m.IsGenericMethod &&
!m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType);
```

Final Code -

```
var stringMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetRuntimeMethod("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(string) });

var dictMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod" && m.IsGenericMethod &&
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType && 
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>));

var genericMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod" && m.IsGenericMethod &&
!m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType);

var listMethodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod" && m.IsGenericMethod &&
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType && 
m.GetGenericMethodDefinition().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>));
```